# SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando usar o código [desse site](http://phppot.com/php/comments-system-using-php-and-ajax/), mas quando vou executar, aparece o erro:

> SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical

Não estou conseguindo localizar o erro. Vejam abaixo:

```
<div class="comment-form-container">
        <form id="frm-comment">
            <div class="input-row">
                <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="commentId"
                    placeholder="Name" /> <input class="input-field"
                    type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-row">
                <textarea class="input-field" type="text" name="comment"
                    id="comment" placeholder="Add a Comment">  </textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="button" class="btn-submit" id="submitButton"
                    value="Publish" /><div id="comment-message">Comments Added Successfully!</div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script>
            function postReply(commentId) {
                $('#commentId').val(commentId);
                $("#name").focus();
            }

            $("#submitButton").click(function () {
                   $("#comment-message").css('display', 'none');
                var str = $("#frm-comment").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "comment-add.php",
                    data: str,
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function (response)
                    {
                        var result = eval('(' + response + ')');
                        if (response)
                        {
                            $("#comment-message").css('display', 'inline-block');
                            $("#name").val("");
                            $("#comment").val("");
                            $("#commentId").val("");
                           listComment();
                        } else
                        {
                            alert("Failed to add comments !");
                            return false;
                        }
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
            });

            $(document).ready(function () {
                   listComment();
            });

            function listComment() {
                $.post("comment-list.php",
                        function (data) {
                               var data = JSON.parse(data);

                            var comments = "";
                            var replies = "";
                            var item = "";
                            var parent = -1;
                            var results = new Array();

                            var list = $("<ul class='outer-comment'>");
                            var item = $("<li>").html(comments);

                            for (var i = 0; (i < data.length); i++)
                            {
                                var commentId = data[i]['comment_id'];
                                parent = data[i]['parent_comment_id'];

                                if (parent == "0")
                                {
                                    comments = "<div class='comment-row'>"+
                                    "<div class='comment-info'><span class='commet-row-label'>from</span> <span class='posted-by'>" + data[i]['comment_sender_name'] + " </span> <span class='commet-row-label'>at</span> <span class='posted-at'>" + data[i]['date'] + "</span></div>" + 
                                    "<div class='comment-text'>" + data[i]['comment'] + "</div>"+
                                    "<div><a class='btn-reply' onClick='postReply(" + commentId + ")'>Reply</a></div>"+
                                    "</div>";

                                    var item = $("<li>").html(comments);
                                    list.append(item);
                                    var reply_list = $('<ul>');
                                    item.append(reply_list);
                                    listReplies(commentId, data, reply_list);
                                }
                            }
                            $("#output").html(list);
                        });
            }

            function listReplies(commentId, data, list) {
                for (var i = 0; (i < data.length); i++)
                {
                    if (commentId == data[i].parent_comment_id)
                    {
                        var comments = "<div class='comment-row'>"+
                        " <div class='comment-info'><span class='commet-row-label'>from</span> <span class='posted-by'>" + data[i]['comment_sender_name'] + " </span> <span class='commet-row-label'>at</span> <span class='posted-at'>" + data[i]['date'] + "</span></div>" + 
                        "<div class='comment-text'>" + data[i]['comment'] + "</div>"+
                        "<div><a class='btn-reply' onClick='postReply(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ")'>Reply</a></div>"+
                        "</div>";
                        var item = $("<li>").html(comments);
                        var reply_list = $('<ul>');
                        list.append(item);
                        item.append(reply_list);
                        listReplies(data[i].comment_id, data, reply_list);
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Quando tento visualizar no console, aparece a seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aparentemente seu código está ok(http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html), deve ser algo com o response :> '('+response+ ') '

Comment: Não entendi isso: `eval('(' + response + ')');`... vc quer executar um response dentro de parênteses? O erro deve estar nisso.

Comment: Muito obrigado pessoal. Era exatamente isso.

Comment: @Fox.11 publica a resposta

Comment: Olá Paulo. Publicado ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme a dica do dvd e PauloHDSousa, fiz a alteração abaixo e funcionou corretamente:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function () {
                $("#comment-message").css('display', 'none');
                var str = $("#frm-comment").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "comment-add.php",
                    data: str,
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function (response)
                    {
                      //  var result = eval('(' + response + ')');
                        if (response)
                        {
                            $("#comment-message").css('display', 'inline-block');
                            $("#name").val("");
                            $("#comment").val("");
                            $("#commentId").val("");
                            listComment();
                        } else
                        {
                            alert("Failed to add comments !");
                            return false;
                        }
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
            });
```